# Sublime text 2, make cannot find pandoc, OSX

Tags: macos, path, makefile, sublimetext2, pandoc

#### Background

My current workflow to create/process markdown documents uses Sublime Text 2 with a Makefile build system, which calls pandoc to process them into PDF documents.

I've recently purchased a new mac, running OSX 10.8.5, and I've been running into some problems.

#### What's working:

I've installed Sublime Text 2, make (from xcode command line tools) and Pandoc (using the package on the website, as the cabal version wouldn't build for me).

#### What's not working:

When I try and build documents, it fails with the following error message from make:

```
pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in -S -o project_specification.pdf project_specification.markdown
make: pandoc: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 2]make: *** [project_specification.pdf] Error 1
```

The makefile however build absolutely fine if I run it using `make` at the terminal.

I think this is a problem with my path, however I'm really not sure how to set it. My understanding is that OSX has multiple paths for different applications (odd to me, as a Linux user until now), and I'm not sure how to set it for sublime to get it to work.

#### More background:

The makefile:

```
CPP_FILES = $(wildcard *.markdown)
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst %.markdown,%.pdf,$(CPP_FILES))

%.pdf: %.markdown
    pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in -S -o $@ $(patsubst %.pdf,%.markdown,$@)

all: $(OBJ_FILES)

clean:
    rm -f *.pdf
```

#### And finally:

I've found similar questions out there, but none with comprehensive answers, so I'm turning to stack overflow once again.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

How about hack the path to wherever your pandoc is?  Sublime Text 2 defaults to:  `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.  This example is for a Tex Live installation using `/usr/texbin`, but you get the idea.  There is one package that comes to mind that is more difficult to hack (e.g., `Shell Turtlestein`), but this works in general for most situations.  I leave this running all the time when I load Sublime Text 2.  If you need the turtle hack, just let me know.  There are ways to adjust the path on a per package build script basis ( e.g., https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/master/LaTeX.sublime-build ), however, the following simplistic plugin usually works:

```
import os

LOCAL = '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin'
HOME = '/Users/HOME'  ### !!! REPLACE WITH YOUR HOME PATH !!! ###
RVM = HOME + '/.rvm/bin:'

# Sublime's default path is
# /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
os.environ['PATH'] += ':'
os.environ['PATH'] += LOCAL
os.environ['PATH'] += RVM

print 'PATH = ' + os.environ['PATH']
```

Comment: Yup, this worked perfectly! Another option for running it is to drop it in a .py file in ~\Library\Application Support\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User as it'll run when ST2 starts.

Comment: Yes, that is one location were user plugins go.  I personally like to use the Packages directory and label my own plugin folders with a dot zero so that they are alphabetized at the top -- e.g., `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/0.pathway/pathway.py`.  I also change the folder name of any package where I modify the source and want to remove it from version control so that my revisions do not get overridden when a package gets updated automatically.  My recollection is that the `User` directory does not permit folders for plugins, and I want to stay organized with folders.